# How to call a component function on other component, but from the other component ? React

Tags: reactjs

Currentl, I am doing a React project. I want to ask:
lets say there are 3 components, A,B, and C.
A is my container, B is the input one, and C is the output one.

this is my component A :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {SubmitComponent} from './submitComponent.js'
// import {OutputCo} from './TopicsContainer.js'

const containerStyle = {
  border: '2px solid black',
  width: '70%',
  height: 'auto',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  marginRight: 'auto',
  marginBottom: '100px',
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={containerStyle}>
        <h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Coding Exercise</h1>
        <hr />
        <SubmitComponent />
        <OutputComponent />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Component B is SubmitComponent, component C is OutputComponent, my B is taking the input and save it as its state :
import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const createstyleouter ={
    border : '2px solid #AAA',
    width : '98%',
    height: 'auto',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    marginTop:'35px',
    marginBottom:'50px',
};

const createstyleinner ={
    // border: '2px solid blue',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    marginTop: '10px',
    width: '98%',

}

export class SubmitComponent extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            desc: ''
        }
        this.newTitle = this.newTitle.bind(this);
        this.newDesc = this.newDesc.bind(this);
    }

    newTitle(e) {
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        });
    }

    newDesc(e) {
        this.setState({
            desc: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={createstyleouter}>
                <div style={createstyleinner}>
                    <p><strong>Title:</strong></p>
                    <textarea style={{width:'100%', height:'20', fontSize:'17px'}} onChange={this.newTitle} maxLength='150' value={this.state.title} placeholder="Enter your topic's title"></textarea>
                    <p>Description:</p>
                    <textarea style={{width:'100%', height:'70', fontSize:'17px'}} onChange={this.newDesc} maxLength='150' value={this.state.desc} placeholder="Enter your topic's description'"></textarea>
                    <button style={{padding: '10px', marginBottom:'10px'}}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I literally did not have any idea how to send this state to C so C can post is as the topic, 
Please help

Comment: just use props. pass a function to the component B that is a submit handler. call it on submit in that component and pass the local state through to the parent App component. The app component can then pass that data down to the other component C

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, let me try

Comment: Hi John, but component A, which is the parent is a container component, I thought it is not a good idea to put some logics and function inside the container ?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to call method from other components, you have to pass method around as `props`.

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // pass method as props to Child component
      <Child parentMethod={this.parentMethod}/>
    );
  }

  parentMethod() {
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Fire parent method</button>
    );
  }

  handleClick() {
    // parent method passed to child is now available as props
    // you can call it now & even pass arguments if you like
    this.props.parentMethod('foo', 'bar', 2, ['foo', 'bar'], {foo: 'bar'});
  }
}
```

If passing around methods gets tricky (e.g one component wants to call a method of component that is in a totally different place in your component tree), you could consider [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

But be warned - read the docs I linked, it makes your code harder to understand and get into.

Comment: Hi solo, but component A, which is the parent is a container component, I thought it is not a good idea to put some logics and function inside the container ?

Comment: @LearntoCode Just the opposite: you bundle all the logic to "smart" parent component that deals with `state` and logic. As many children as possible should be "dumb" components that mostly just receive (preferably scalar and/or immutable) values and render. Why is that good? It's simpler for developer, all the logic is in one place + children are "dumb" and simple: you can reuse them in other situations + if you get performance problems: because they only recieve and render, you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` method to avoid unnecessary code/rendering.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of the parent:

```
this.childElement = React.createRef();
```

In your child element in the parent:

```
<Child ref = {this.childElement}>
```

To call a method of the child use:

```
this.childElement.current.aFunctionInChildClass();
```

For more information in [react documentation/refs and the dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [lift the state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so state is passed as props from container to child components.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, but component A, which is the parent is a container component, I thought it is not a good idea to put some logics and function inside the container ?

Comment: Why not? If you are talking from perspective of container vs presentational components (https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) then container is exactly the place where your logic should be.

Comment: what if each component is independent, I mean no parent no child.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have a structure

```
class A
{
getResponse:function(res)
{
set you state//
this.setState({
state:res
})

}
<B state={this.state} callback={this.getResponse}/>
<C state={this.state}  />//state is the updated state by function callback

}
```

in Component B you need to call function callback as

```
class B
{
callAComponent:function(res)
{
this.props.callback(res)

}
render{

return(

<input type="text" onChange={this.callAComponent}//whaever event you are performing
)

}
}
```

Now send the update state in C component