# Call function from React component in other component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

Can you help me?
I have two functional components and I need to use function from first component in second component.
I want to use function "sayHello" in function onClicked, but I don't know how to do it.

```
import React from 'react';

type Props = {

}

const Component_1: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {

  const sayHello = () => {

    console.log('----Hello');
    
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="">
      Component 1
    </div>
  );
};
    
export default React.memo(Component_1);


const Component_2: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {

  const onClicked = () => {
    
    //How ???
    //Component_1.sayHello()

  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      
      <div onClick={onClicked}>
        Click me
      </div>

      <Component_1/>

    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi,

Please look into the following link:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262987/how-to-call-a-component-function-on-other-component-but-from-the-other-componen

This might resolve your issue.

Comment: there are components-class but I have components-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Component_1 = (props) => {
 const sayHello = () => {
  console.log("----Hello");
 };
 props.onClicked(sayHello);
 return <div className="">Component 1</div>;
};

const Component_2 = () => {
 let sayHello;
 const fn = function (sayHelloFromComp1) {
  sayHello = sayHelloFromComp1;
 };

 const onClicked = (e) => {
 //How ???
 //Component_1.sayHello()
 sayHello();
 };
 return (
  <div className="">
   <div onClick={onClicked}>Click me</div>
   <Component_1 onClicked={fn} />
  </div>
 );
};

export default Component_2;
```